# how to create a custom datatype in java?

Tags: java

I want to create an custom datatype in Java,for example datatype Email , that having following method isValidate(String email),isEmailExist(String email),getDomain(String email), get Id(String email),just like Integer class in java.

Integer is a class and I can initialise the object of Integer class as follows:

```
Integer i = 100;
```

I created my class Email and I want to initialise it as follows

```
Email e = "sam";
```

How can i perform this functionality in my Email class.

```
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;
```

public class Email
{
   private String email;
    public Email(String email)
    {
        this.email=email;
    }

```
Email() {  
}

public Boolean isvalid(String email)
{
```

String lastToken = null;
   Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".+@.+\.[a-z]+");
   // Match the given string with the pattern
   Matcher m = p.matcher(email);
   // check whether match is found
   boolean matchFound = m.matches();
   StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(email, ".");
   while (st.hasMoreTokens())
   {
      lastToken = st.nextToken();
   }

if (matchFound && lastToken.length() >= 2
      && email.length() - 1 != lastToken.length())
   {
      return true;
   }
   else
      return false;
   }
  public String toString() {
    return email;
    }
}

Thanks

Comment: You'll need to learn the basics of creating a class in Java. Here's an online tutorial: [Classes in Java](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classes.html)

Comment: The only thing that you *won't* be able to do is `Email e = "sam";`. You will need `Email e = new Email("sam");` instead.

Comment: I think that the OP is asking how to do something known as "implicit operator overloading". That would make this question a not-so-beginner question after all. 
In Java this is noticeable when using the wrapper types. When you assign a literal to a java.lang.Integer for example.
The answer is that Java does not support creating custom types that allow this. So you cannot do Email email = "someone@example.com".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an Email class. Java 101; any book or free tutorial of the Java language will get you started.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot instantiate it as you write, the closest would be using a constructor:

```
Email e = new Email("Sam");
```